# Is it possible to implement an undo/redo engine with JavascriptMVC?

Tags: undo-redo, javascriptmvc

Is it possible to implement an undo/redo engine with JavascriptMVC?

Answer (score 2):

Probably. While I've never worked with JavascriptMVC, here is the principle how undo works:

1. Instead of directly changing anything, you put the code to change something in a "command" object. The command object has two methods: `undo()` and `redo()`.
2. When an operation is executed, you create the necessary command objects, invoke `redo()` on them and add them to a list (the "undo stack").
3. For undo, pop items off the list and invoke `undo()` on them and push them on the "redo stack".
4. For redo, pop from the "redo stack", invoke `redo()` and push the item on the undo stack.

It doesn't matter whether you do this on the server or on the client but I suggest that you chose one side and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to use it for?  Instead of using undo/redo, can you use it's history plugin?  That way undo/redo will work with the forward and back buttons.